# How to add slides (images) to bxslider?

Tags: plugins

[image: Don't know where to add slides?]

Hi there,

I'd much appreciate if someone can help me out. I don't know where to add slides (or images) to BXSlider. In common guideline, it should be an add slides options underneath "bxSlider Intergration", but I don't see it.

I have tried it on WP 4.2 and 4.3.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The [bxSlider](https://wordpress.org/plugins/bxslider-integration/) plugin which you are using just converts the page/post galleries into slider. It does not provide any separate option as such to upload the images.

Perhaps you should use [BxSlider WP](https://wordpress.org/plugins/bxslider-wp/) plugin if you want a separate section to create multiple sliders and upload images under each of them. I hope this helps.